# Why does Flex recognize paddingLeft as a property on a component, but not as part of a style?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

In my application this works:

```
<s:VGroup width="100%" paddingLeft="100">
... stuff ...
</s:VGroup>
```

This doesn't:

```
<fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
        .myStyle {
            paddingLeft: 100;
        }
    </fx:Style>
<s:VGroup width="100%" styleName="myStyle">
... stuff ...
</s:VGroup>
```

Why not?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
s|VGroup.myStyle {
```